# how to run a python script as soon as another process ends

Tags: linux, python-2.7

there is a process running that will write some output to a set of files. I wrote a python script that will make a copy of these output files in another directory. Right now I can simply run the python script when I notice the other process is done. How can I get this script to be run automatically when the other process is done?

I don't have control over the other process's source code. Messing with the source code might make the results file inadmissible, so I'd rather not touch it at all.

I am running Python 2.7.1 in an Ubuntu 11.x machine.

Comment: If you are using [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) you could use `pyqtSignal` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't tell much about what is the program running before the Python script, but if it is or you can convert to a shell script, you can use this syntax:

```
$ first-script.sh && python-script.sh
```

The `&&` operator means that if the first script finished successfully, run the second afterwards.

Of course, you could invoke the python interpreter with your script directly as the 2nd script. Here I assume that it is wrapped in a Bash script.